# How do I fill a shape with a gradient on Android?

Tags: android, gradient

How do I fill a shape with a gradient on Android? Like, for instance, LinearGradient, RadialGradient, or SweepGradient.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243230/android-image-gradient

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do it from xml. Create a xml file in drawables folder, the file should like this

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<!-- fill stroke color  -->
<stroke
    android:width="1dip"
    android:color="#bd5426" />
<!-- gradient color   -->
<gradient
    android:angle="-270"
    android:endColor="#B4BBBD"
    android:centerColor="#color you want"
    android:startColor="#D9DFE0" />

 
</shape>
```

finally you use in  your view like

```
android:background="@color/name_of_xml_defined_above"
```

Comment: Thank you.But how can i fill a star with gradient?The XML you showed offered a linear gradient instead of path gradient.

Comment: this should be in `drawable` folder not `color`